# How to remove yourself from issue participants in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I know how to leave the entire project, but I do not wish to do so.

There is an issue I accidentally create a branch for, and the branch is being used by actual participants, but I'm not doing anything for that issue's resolution. Now because I am a participant, I get an email whenever any of the other two participants does something.

I am listed on the right sidebar's Participants section, but there is no Edit button, like there is for other sections.

[image: 2 actual participants and then me as a supposed participant]

How do I remove myself or otherwise prevent getting emails from said issue?

Comment: There must be a toggle "Notifications". Set this toggle off prevent getting mails.

Comment: That would work for *all* emails. I just want to silence this particular issue.

Comment: Thats not true. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/notifications.html#edit-notification-settings-for-issues-merge-requests-and-epics -> "To unsubscribe, turn off if you are receiving notifications for updates but no longer want to receive them.
Turning this toggle off only unsubscribes you from updates related to this issue, merge request, or epic. Learn how to opt out of all emails from GitLab."

Comment: I literally just checked Settings > Notifications, and all you can do is select "Global notification level", per "Group(s)" or per "Project(s)" from their respective dropdowns. There is no option to change Settings > Notifications > MyProject > TheirIssue, and it's that last part that I want to change. Not settings for my entire project. Not even with "Custom" next to MyProject.

Comment: The button "Notificications" is next to your Issue (https://imgur.com/a/vuPu34C)

Comment: Sometimes you just can’t see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*[@Jakob Liskow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3535187/jakob-liskow) answered in the comments.*

When you have an issue opened in your browser, there's a sidebar on the right. In that sidebar there's a section listing all participant and right under it, there is a toggle labelled "Notifications".

[image: Notifications are ON]

You need to turn this off in order to not receive any email.

[image: Notifications are OFF]

#### Note

As O'Rooney pointed out in the comments below, this does not actually remove you as a participant, rather you no longer receive notifications for the issue in question. If you expect you might be needed in the same issue at a later point in time, you probably should not mute notifications, or your collaborators would best be informed of your decision so they can explicitly ping you on the matter when the need arises.

Comment: Does this actually remove you as a participant, or leave you there but mute notifications? It seems like the latter, which is a risk, because if I later become active on the issue, its not going to notify me still.

Comment: This is how you mute your own notification yourself at your own risk, as you figured out. In practice, issues are usually small enough tasks to not have the need to come back before they're completed. Regardless of how you feel about it, the answer is exactly what I needed. I will now upvote your comment and add it to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably not too likely to matter in practice. Thanks